# MongoDB is very slow in upserting

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mlab

I use mlab MongoDB and I have now about 1,500,000 Documents in my database and I use node.js as server side (heroku) to add data to my database.
But when data became large, work became slow and I lost some data because of "request timeout"

this my node.js code

```
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID
var async = require("async");

module.exports = function(app, db) {
const myDb = db.db('sycontacts') 

app.post('/addcontacts', (req, res) => {
    const jason = JSON.parse(req.body.body);

    async.eachOfLimit(jason, 20, function(value, index, callback){

        myDb.collection('contacts').update(
            { n: value.n, p: value.p }, {n: value.n, p: value.p}, {multi: false, upsert: true}, function(err){

            return callback(err);

        });

    }, function(err, result){

        // all is finished
        if(err)
        {
            return res.status(500).json({err: err});
        }
        else
        {
            return res.status(200).json({err: null});
        }
        db.close()
    })
});
```

Can anyone help me؟

Comment: Do you have a compound index on `n` and `p`?

Comment: yes I have compound index on n and p

Comment: Roughly what percentage of documents you're upserting already exist?

Comment: Very low percentage, most of the documents are new